# Angular2 Material md-icon size

Tags: angular, material-design

How do I get the icon size to work with the relative size of the font in angular2?

```
<div style="font-size: 3em;">
<md-icon>highlight</md-icon>
Title
</div>
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

In your CSS file you can modify the md-icon size by modifying font-size, height and width. For example:

```
md-icon.size-45 {
    font-size: 45px;
    height: 45px;
    width: 45px;
}
```

Answer (score -2):

There are two ways to approach this.

You can influence the ligature itself:

```
<md-icon><h1>highlight</h1></md-icon>
```

This will resize the icon, but it will be influenced by styles set on the header elements (like `font-weight`). So, **I would recommend resizing using CSS:**

```
<md-icon style="font-size:24px">highlight<md-icon>
```

This will resize the icon crisply. You can of course also add classes to do that (which is even better!):

```
<md-icon class="large">highlight<md-icon>
```

Comment: It would be nice to hear why I'm getting downvoted? We're all here to learn.

Comment: Didn't downvote, but I tried your examples by using the [Angular Documentation](https://material.angular.io/components/button/examples), switch from there to plunker and they didn't work.

Comment: Did you try the second suggestion from my answer? It works if I take the last button and added `style="font-size: 50px;"` to the `<md-icon>` tag

Comment: The first idea seems to suggest using markup to influence style, which is a violation of semantic document structure and may create accessibility issues. I suspect that's what garnered the downvotes.